# can u explain me why function file* doesnt work in C?

Tags: c, file, debugging

I have many errors and i don't know why they are? 
I want to create files movies.txt and write some ideas. And when i tried build this program i couldnt.

```
||=== Build: Debug in projekt nr 6 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
XXX\...\|6|error: unknown type name 'FILE'|
XXX\...\|7|warning: data definition has no type or storage class|
XXX\...\|7|warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'plik' [-Wimplicit-int]|
XXX\...\|7|error: conflicting types for 'plik'|
XXX\...\|6|note: previous declaration of 'plik' was here|
XXX\...\|7|warning: implicit declaration of function 'fopen' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
XXX\...\|7|error: initializer element is not constant|
XXX\...\|8|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'if'|
XXX\...\|14|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant|
XXX\...\|15|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant|
XXX\...\|15|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token|
XXX\...\|17|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant|
XXX\...\|18|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant|
XXX\...\main.c||In function 'main':|
XXX\...\main.c|45|error: expected identifier or '*' before '(' token|
||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
XXX\...\|18|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token|
XXX\...\|20|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant|
XXX\...\|21|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant|
XXX\...\|21|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token|
XXX\...\|23|error: expected ')' before string constant|
XXX\...\|24|warning: data definition has no type or storage class|
XXX\...\|24|warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'fclose' [-Wimplicit-int]|
XXX\...\|24|warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration|
||=== Build failed: 15 error(s), 6 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is my code data.c (not main.c):

```
   char title, genre;
int year;

FILE *plik;
plik=fopen("movies.txt", "a");
if(plik == NULL)
   {
   perror("Błąd otwarcia pliku");
   exit(-10);
   }

printf("Podaj nazwe filmu: ");
scanf("%s", &title);

printf("Podaj rok produkcji: ");
scanf("%s", &year);

printf("Podaj gatunek filmu: ");
scanf("%s", &genre);

fprintf(plik,"%s %s %d", title,genre,year);
fclose(plik);
```

PS. How to connect this data.c to main.c in function switch case?

Comment: This is not the *whole* code, is it?

Comment: its whole code of data.c

Comment: "PS. How to connect this data.c to main.c in function switch case?" Break that off into a different question, and rephrase that .  I don't know what that means.

Comment: Then it is completely invalid Just some dangling expressions. Executable code needs to have some execution context, such as a function.

Comment: It may be all of `data.c` But the compile errors don't correspond with the code you posted @PabloKwiatkowski. And as has been stated you can't call functions at the top level, what you posted is not in fact a valid c source file.

Comment: @PabloKwiatkowski: Please tell me you aren't simply `#include`-ing `data.c` into `main.c`.  That's bad practice.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so i have to add "#include <stdio.h> int main(){}... ?

Comment: after some changes , all works good but movies.txt is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FILE* works in C just fine, but your code has to be valid.  From the comments its clear yours was not.  No programming language lends itself well to guessing your way through it, but C is a particularly bad choice if you choose to take such an approach, as its very unforgiving.

here's how to show code.  Notice I include all the relevant code, only the relevant code, showed how I built it, how I invoked it, and what happened when it ran.  If I only showed the parts inside `main()` it wouldn't be the same.

```
$ cat t.c ; gcc -o t2 t.c && { ./t2; ./t2; ./t2; cat movies.txt;}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
  FILE* f = fopen("movies.txt", "a");
  if( f == NULL) {
      perror("Couldn't open file");
      return 1;
  }
  fprintf(f, "Wrote to file from PID %d\n", getpid());
}

Wrote to file from PID 71729
Wrote to file from PID 71741
Wrote to file from PID 71747
Wrote to file from PID 71767
Wrote to file from PID 71782
Wrote to file from PID 71783
Wrote to file from PID 71784
```

Comment: ok but i have next problem , because when i write something to save to file my movies.txt is empty

Comment: Give me a complete example like I did and I'll tell you why it didn't work.  I can't possibly tell you why code I've never seen doesn't work in ways that have never been described.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iPPRCNXz?fbclid=IwAR2SYaGvm5oICel849EHa4NTMCs_O4zBAgDJBiZM_kz8uuhyzPdlHs4mBWU

Comment: That's a great candidate for a new Stack Overflow question.  Include that relevant code _and the output and errors you receive_ and the community will help you.  You need to include the output in the question, not just the code.  And make sure it's clear what you're trying to achieve .  Don't link to code on pastebin, put it right in the question where it can be edited and discussed directly.